# Rational numbers modulo $p$ for some prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, valuation-theory

Given a rational  number $\frac{a}{b}$ and a prime $p$ such that $p\not\mid b$, we say that $\frac{a}{b} \equiv 0  \pmod p$ if $p \mid a$. Also, we say for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\alpha \equiv \beta \pmod p$ if $\alpha - \beta \equiv 0$.

Now, I have to questions:

1. What should I think if I consider modulo $p$ equivalence of some rational number $\alpha$? Is it a number between $0$ and $p-1$ such that it is $0$ if above holds and some number different than $0$ otherwise?
2. How can I show the following:

> Given a rational $\alpha \equiv 0 \pmod p$, there exists a unique number $q$, $0 \le q < p$ such that $q \equiv \frac{1}{p} \alpha \pmod p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.- Simply $\dfrac ab=\dfrac {ab^{-1}}{bb^{-1}}=ab^{-1}$ and $\dfrac ab\equiv0\iff \dfrac ab=Mp$

Comment: How about $1.$?

Comment: $1$ is la "class" of numbers $Mp+1$

Comment: what is $b^{-1}$? Is it the inverse of $b$ modulo $p$?

Comment: Yes, obviously. All is happening in the field $\mathbb F_p$